# javascript mouse input event not responding

Tags: javascript

I'm trying make a p5js tic-tac-toe game but the `mousePressed` function is not working.

Is there another way I can do this or how can I solve this problem?
I tried calling the function `mousePressed` but I don't want to spam the console I instead want a `mouseClick` event.

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
}

function draw() {
  background(255);
  frameRate(60);

  function grid() {
    strokeWeight(2);
    //up
    u1 = rect(80, 92, 75, 70);
    u2 = rect(155, 92, 75, 70);
    u3 = rect(230, 92, 75, 70);
    //middle
    rect(230, 162, 75, 70);
    rect(80, 162, 75, 70);
    rect(155, 162, 75, 70);
    //bottom
    rect(230, 232, 75, 70);
    rect(80, 232, 75, 70);
    rect(155, 232, 75, 70);
  }

  function cursor() {
    frameRate(70);
    strokeWeight(5);
    cursor = circle(mouseX, mouseY, 2);
    text("X:" + mouseX, 0, height / 4);
    text("Y:" + mouseY, 0, height / 2);
  }

  function mousePressed() {
    if (mouseX > 80 && mouseX < 155 && mouseY > 92 && mouseY < 160) {
      console.log('In u1');
    }
  }
  grid();
  cursor();

}

function changeColor() {
  let elem = document.getElementById('asd');
  elem.style.color = 'red'
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.2.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should move your `mousePressed` event callback function outside of the `draw` function. It will start working after that. See the example below.

You can also remove all the hard-coded values by looping over the rows/cols or determing the x/y positions ahead of time and assigning them to `const` variable.

**Edit:** I changed the `mousePressed` event to loop over all the cells to determine which cell index was clicked.

```js
const startX    = 80 , startY     = 92;
const cellWidth = 75 , cellHeight = 70;
const rowCount  =  3 , colCount   =  3;

const x1 = startX;
const x2 = startX + cellWidth;
const x3 = startX + (cellWidth * 2);

const y1 = startY;
const y2 = startY + cellHeight;
const y3 = startY + (cellHeight * 2);

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
}

function draw() {
  background(255);
  frameRate(60);
  
  function grid() {
    strokeWeight(2);
    // Top
    u1 = rect(x1, y1, cellWidth, cellHeight);
    u2 = rect(x2, y1, cellWidth, cellHeight);
    u3 = rect(x3, y1, cellWidth, cellHeight);
    // Middle
    rect(x1, y2, cellWidth, cellHeight);
    rect(x2, y2, cellWidth, cellHeight);
    rect(x3, y2, cellWidth, cellHeight);
    // Bottom
    rect(x1, y3, cellWidth, cellHeight);
    rect(x2, y3, cellWidth, cellHeight);
    rect(x3, y3, cellWidth, cellHeight);
  }

  function cursor() {
    frameRate(70);
    strokeWeight(5);
    cursor = circle(mouseX, mouseY, 2);
    text("X:" + mouseX, 0, height / 4);
    text("Y:" + mouseY, 0, height / 2);
  }

  grid();
  cursor();
}

function mousePressed() {
  for (let x = 0; x < colCount; x++) {
    for (let y = 0; y < rowCount; y++) {
      const xMin = startX + (x * cellWidth);
      const yMin = startY + (y * cellHeight);
      const xMax = xMin + cellWidth;
      const yMax = yMin + cellHeight;
      if (mouseX > xMin && mouseX < xMax && mouseY > yMin && mouseY < yMax) {
        const index = y * colCount + x;
        console.log(`index = ${index} | row = ${y + 1} | col = ${x + 1}`);
      }
    }
  }
}

function changeColor() {
  let elem = document.getElementById('asd');
  elem.style.color = 'red'
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.2.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

---

### Dynamically drawing

You can draw the grid based on a context. This can be stored inside of a JSON file.

```js
const context = {
  width: 400,
  height: 400,
  grid: {
    origin: {
      x: 80,
      y: 92
    },
    cell: {
      width: 75,
      height: 70
    },
    rows: 3,
    cols: 3
  }
};

function setup() {
  const { width, height } = context;
  createCanvas(width, height);
}

function draw() {
  background(255);
  frameRate(60);

  function grid() {
    const {
      grid: {
        rows,
        cols,
        cell: {
          width: cellWidth,
          height: cellHeight
        },
        origin: {
          x: xOffset,
          y: yOffset
        }
      }
    } = context;
    strokeWeight(2);
    for (let row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
      for (let col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
        let x = xOffset + (col * cellWidth);
        let y = yOffset + (row * cellHeight);
        rect(x, y, cellWidth, cellHeight)
      }
    }
  }

  function cursor() {
    frameRate(70);
    strokeWeight(5);
    cursor = circle(mouseX, mouseY, 2);
    text("X:" + mouseX, 0, height / 4);
    text("Y:" + mouseY, 0, height / 2);
  }

  grid();
  cursor();
}

function mousePressed() {
  const {
    grid: {
      rows,
      cols,
      cell: {
        width: cellWidth,
        height: cellHeight
      },
      origin: {
        x: xOffset,
        y: yOffset
      }
    }
  } = context;

  for (let row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
    for (let col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
      const xMin = xOffset + (col * cellWidth);
      const yMin = yOffset + (row * cellHeight);
      const xMax = xMin + cellWidth;
      const yMax = yMin + cellHeight;
      if (mouseX > xMin && mouseX < xMax && mouseY > yMin && mouseY < yMax) {
        const index = row * cols + col;
        console.log(`index = ${index} | row = ${row + 1} | col = ${col + 1}`);
      }
    }
  }
}

function changeColor() {
  let elem = document.getElementById('asd');
  elem.style.color = 'red'
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.2.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You figured it out. The mousePressed function was bound to the context of Draw function. Therefore it could not be accessed from outside as a callback function. (the way the P5 framework works). Moving it outside of the draw function solved it.